# Compare picture in imageview to resources?

Tags: android, imageview, android-resources

I'm new to android programming, and wondered if there is a way to compare a specific picture in an imageview to a resource image to see whether they are the same? Thank you in advance!

Comment: same as in? content? size? color? what have you tried?

Comment: Same as in the same content. A picture of a dice pops up and the user is supposed to enter the number of dots. So, when they type in the number I need to know what picture is in the imageview at that time to compare to the resource image. I haven't tried anything because I have been researching but haven't found any information..if you know a better way to do this, please let me know and thank you!!

Comment: You don't want to compare the images -- since you're already displaying the image, you would already know which one it is, and you would know the number of dots, wouldn't you?

Comment: No because the image is randomly displayed from an array in a loop so it changes...So I need to be able to see which image is in the imageview at the current time..thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u initialize imageview use to setTag("1")
and when u want to check then use if(imageview.getTag("1")) and u can do whatever operation u like..